# What does `&[][..]` mean in Rust?

Tags: rust, syntax

I am going through a crate `hifijson` to parse the JSON source code and I stumbled upon this:

```
fn skip_until(&mut self, stop: impl FnMut(u8) -> bool) {
    use crate::Write;
    self.write_until(&mut &[][..], stop) // <-
}
```

You can check out complete implementation [here](https://github.com/01mf02/hifijson/blob/cdcfe9fa8510e882ac1dfbeef078b4e07664836e/src/read.rs#L36).

I am little unsure about the syntax `&[][..]` on line which is marked with comment `<-` above. Although I think that it is passing the `bytes` field as mutable slice of `struct` `SliceLexer` here, but I have never seen this syntax before anywhere in rust documentation or elsewhere.

May someone explain how it works and confirm if it is only applicable here since struct has only one field which is a borrowed slice and if this syntax is documented somewhere?

Comment: `&mut [].as_slice()` would make the intention somewhat clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[]` is an array literal of 0 elements, `[..]` is indexing using a range, and `&` takes a reference, so `&[][..]` creates an empty slice reference, often referred to as just a slice.

It is not connected to `self` in any way other than you're passing it to a method of `self`.